# Python script using Xgboost in linux: terminate called recursively, src/data/././strtonum.h:141:Check failed: sign == true (0 vs. 1)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, xgboost

I'm totally new to either use Xgboost or to compile and build python scripts on shell remotely access to server's Ubuntu 14.
So please forgive me for asking such question because I haven't found the solution on Stack Overflow yet.

The project goal is to use xgboost in python extracting features among user behavior data. For the purpose of testing loading data for xgboost, I just wrote a short script to do it, shown as follow.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
import pickle
import xgboost as xgb

# /home/mjoys/user_profile
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix('/home/mjoys/user_profile/data/goods_items/textdata.txt')
print dtrain
```

Cuz I'm new at building python file in Linux, I've done it again in the windows environment.The scripts in windows and Linux are basically the same, except for the directory.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse
import pickle
import xgboost as xgb

# /home/mjoys/user_profile
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix('E:/user profile/test_xgboost/data/goods_items/textdata.txt')
print dtrain
```

To my surprise, the compile of windows script is successful but the Linux one went wrong.
Could you please look at it and tell me what is wrong with the Linux one?
Thanks a lot.

windows result:

```
D:\Anaconda2\python.exe "E:/user profile/test_xgboost/test1"
<xgboost.core.DMatrix object at 0x000000000664AC18>
143x0 matrix with 0 entries is loaded from E:/user 
profile/test_xgboost/data/goods_items/textdata.txt

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Linux result:

```
mjoys@ml001:~/user_profile$ python ./test.py
[17:27:04] dmlc-core/include/dmlc/logging.h:300: [17:27:04] 
src/data/././strtonum.h:141: Check failed: sign == true (0 vs. 1) 

Stack trace returned 6 entries:
[bt] (0) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-
py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc15LogMessageFatalD1Ev+0x39) 
[0x7fb75b398279]
[bt] (1) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-
py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc4data9strtouintIiEET_PKcPPci+0xd4) 
[0x7fb75b4ecbd4]
[bt] (2) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6- py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc4data12LibSVMParserIjE10ParseBlockEPcS3_PNS0_17RowBlockContainerIjEE+0x171) [0x7fb75b4fdb81]
[bt] (3) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1(+0x834a) [0x7fb75b12734a]
[bt] (4) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8184) [0x7fb765b95184]
[bt] (5) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fb7658c2bed]

[17:27:04] dmlc-core/include/dmlc/logging.h:300: [17:27:04] src/data/././strtonum.h:141: Check failed: sign == true (0 vs. 1) 

Stack trace returned 6 entries:
[bt] (0) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc15LogMessageFatalD1Ev+0x39) [0x7fb75b398279]
[bt] (1) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc4data9strtouintIiEET_PKcPPci+0xd4) [0x7fb75b4ecbd4]
[bt] (2) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc4data12LibSVMParserIjE10ParseBlockEPcS3_PNS0_17RowBlockContainerIjEE+0x171) [0x7fb75b4fdb81]
[bt] (3) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1(+0x834a) [0x7fb75b12734a]
[bt] (4) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8184) [0x7fb765b95184]
[bt] (5) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fb7658c2bed]

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dmlc::Error'
terminate called recursively
what():  [17:27:04] src/data/././strtonum.h:141: Check failed: sign == true (0 vs. 1) 

Stack trace returned 6 entries:
[bt] (0) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc15LogMessageFatalD1Ev+0x39) [0x7fb75b398279]
[bt] (1) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc4data9strtouintIiEET_PKcPPci+0xd4) [0x7fb75b4ecbd4]
[bt] (2) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc4data12LibSVMParserIjE10ParseBlockEPcS3_PNS0_17RowBlockContainerIjEE+0x171) [0x7fb75b4fdb81]
[bt] (3) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1(+0x834a) [0x7fb75b12734a]
[bt] (4) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8184) [0x7fb765b95184]
[bt] (5) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fb7658c2bed]

[17:27:04] dmlc-core/include/dmlc/logging.h:300: [17:27:04] src/data/././strtonum.h:141: Check failed: sign == true (0 vs. 1) 

Stack trace returned 6 entries:
[bt] (0) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc15LogMessageFatalD1Ev+0x39) [0x7fb75b398279]
[bt] (1) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc4data9strtouintIiEET_PKcPPci+0xd4) [0x7fb75b4ecbd4]
[bt] (2) /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xgboost-0.6-py2.7.egg/xgboost/libxgboost.so(_ZN4dmlc4data12LibSVMParserIjE10ParseBlockEPcS3_PNS0_17RowBlockContainerIjEE+0x171) [0x7fb75b4fdb81]
[bt] (3) /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1(+0x834a) [0x7fb75b12734a]
[bt] (4) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8184) [0x7fb765b95184]
[bt] (5) /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fb7658c2bed]

terminate called recursively
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: You may want to show what line 141 (and the lines surrounding it) of src/data/././strtonum.h include. Also, reading [ask] may be beneficial.